# Can a lambda expression be beta-equal to beta-normal forms?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

Given a Lambda Expression Term T can it be beta-equal to two different  Lambda Terms T1 and T2, both T1 and T2 are in beta-normal form?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  We discourage posts that consist solely of a problem statement.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I would suggest studying [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem).